# Page sliding on a desktop webapp similar to iPhone webapps

Tags: jquery, mootools, scriptaculous, iui

I've looked at [ciui](http://clientside.cnet.com/cnet-js-standards/ciui-cnet-iphone-ui/) and really liked the way that certain links will slide out the existing content and load new content into the DOM, or slide back.

Is there a way to quickly create a work-a-like with the additional animation support in jQuery, scriptaculous, or MooTools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming to this very old discussion, http://www.jqtouch.com/ is a more recent solution that works very well for this.  It's a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/iui/

This is the best iPhone javascript library I've seen so far, and it does page sliding.

Comment: The library I mentioned, `ciui`, is just a different `iui` fork. Neither are made to work on top of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the jQuery UI project and see if anything there does what you need. The best code is code you don't have to write. :)

http://ui.jquery.com/repository/latest/demos/functional/

Comment: That link broke. http://jqueryui.com/demos/ is considerably more of a traditional UI than it is a kind of iPhone app UI implementation. Which would mean I need to write this myself, or find something else.